# how to enlarge the sidebar or add a horizontal scrollbar in sphinx (sphinx_rtd_theme)?

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, sidebar

I'm a newbie in Sphinx and CSS. Basically when I try to automatically generate the documentation by simply adding 'modules' to default conf.py and using sphinx_rtd_theme, I get too long names (fully qualified domain name) on the sidebar that are not fully displayed because of short sidebar's width.

Is there any way to solve this issue?
Adding a horizontal scrollbar? Or enlarge the sidebar's width? Or?

[image: sidebar screenshot]

Comment: See your theme's documentation for options. In general you can override your theme's default CSS with a specific style. Assuming this is the RTD theme, you can add `overflow-x: auto;` to `.wy-menu-vertical` to allow horizontal scrolling to the nav container for long names without whitespace.

Comment: Thanks. I added in this piece of code in conf.py. `html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme' html_theme_options = {     'collapse_navigation': False,     'display_version': False,     'navigation_depth': 6, }  html_static_path = ['_static'] html_css_files = [     'custom.css' ]`
In _static foder I put custom.css file with just this content:  `.wy-menu-vertical {     overflow-x: auto; }`
Unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: Please update your question with your code. It is unreadable in a comment. Also include what theme you are using. Some themes have different methods to customize their styles.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to arrange the lateral navigational menu is to use custom CSS to enable horizontal scroll-bar.

The steps to do that are few:

1. Find the div class that wraps the lateral menu (you can use the browser inspector). In the `Classic` theme the name is `sphinxsidebarwrapper`;
2. In `_static` folder add a new file called `custom.css` (or other name if you want). If you have one folder for `build` and one for `source` (depends on choice made during sphinx-quickstart), use the `_static` folder in `source` folder.
   The CSS file have to contain only one rule:

   ```
   .sphinxsidebarwrapper {  overflow-y: scroll; }
   ```
3. Add in `conf.py` the line below, after `html_static_path = ['_static']`:

   ```
   html_css_files = ["custom.css"]
   ```